# Get top 2 scores from a column in df respect to another column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My df:

```
  parent child       score

0   O    Tel         0.294015
1   O    The         0.296218
2   O    Tri         0.306937
3   O    nal         0.290132
4   O    rap         0.298493

5   PV   Aer         0.297987
6   PV   Arc         0.277228
7   PV   Bro         0.301921
8   PV   CAS         0.286482
```

I want like:

```
0   O    Tri         0.306937
1   O    rap         0.298493
2   PV   Aer         0.297987
3   PV   Bro         0.301921
```

Need to get top 2 scores of the parent with child,
not multi-indexed.

Comment: What have you tried?  grouping and sorting (for top-2 values) are both covered well in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one liner that will do this - which will also take into consideration of cases that parent only has 1 child.

```
df.groupby('parent').apply(lambda df: df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).iloc[:2] if len(df) > 1 else df)
```

Comment: The logic here is fine, though the result can be obtained much more succintly with `df.sort_values('score').groupby('parent').tail(2).sort_index()`. This also will not add an extra `multiIndex` redundant with `parent`

Answer (score 2):

Using `tail`

```
df.sort_values(['parent','score']).groupby('parent').tail(2)
Out[932]: 
  parent child     score
4      O   rap  0.298493
2      O   Tri  0.306937
5     PV   Aer  0.297987
7     PV   Bro  0.301921
```